# Apply a function on a dict's items

Tags: python

Basically, I am looking for a way to rewrite the following in a simpler, more pythonic fashion:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    function(key, value)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: That looks pretty simple and Pythonic to me.

Comment: This looks Pythonic enough, just use `.iteritems()` in case you are on Python 2 and dictionary is big.

Comment: I was looking for something rather "one-liner", I thought it is possible.

Comment: One line eh?... `for key, value in dictionary.items(): function(key, value)`

Comment: This is fine. If you need the values, rewrite as a list comprehension. You could also splat the k,v pair in order to reduce readability.

Comment: For a one-liner, either define `function` to accept the whole dictionary as argument (and iterate within the function), or - if you want to keep the original function as it is and need to do this iteration many times - create another function that accepts the dictionary, and does what you just wrote.  
Then of course the function would return a list, so you'd need to iterate through that list, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do

```
from itertools import starmap
from collections import deque

exhaust_iterable = deque(maxlen=0).extend

exhaust_iterable(starmap(function, dictionary.items()))
```

if you *really* want to...

Comment: Accepting this answer as the best alternative to my approach, but probably will stick to that one as I was confirmed that is the best approach for what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

This is a one-liner. Not sure I'd consider it "more pythonic", though

```
map(function, *zip(*d.iteritems()))
```

Comment: Note: despite the `iter` in the `iteritems`, this takes `O(n)` memory.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing much to factor out, but may be something that could be useful is

```
def dictmap(f, d):
    return {k: f(k, v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

then you can write

```
result = dictmap(function, dictionary)
```

(given that keys are enumerated in a random order returning a list with the result doesn't make much sense and  dictionary seems more appropriate).

Note however that for reasons that are not so clear to me `map` and functional reasoning is sort of considered bad in the Python community (for example anonymous functions are second-class citizens and they got quite close to be completely removed from Python 3).

Comment: It looks good, but I don't need to return those values from my function. `function` acts as a validator and raises exceptions is something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
[function(x, y) for x, y in d.items()]
```

Comment: This is really bad practice... `for x, y in d.items(): function(x, y)` is actually shorter and doesn't build a pointless list.